# Mysqli Prepare Statement Insert Not Inserting

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm already connected to the database. When I echo all of the variables, they work, but they just will not insert into my database table. I have the table name correct. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$pid = '1'; 
$pname = 'name'; 
$poster_id = '2';
$poster_name = 'name2'; 
$message = 'This is the message';

$datetime = date("M d, Y");

// insert into database
$ins  = "INSERT INTO messages (profile_id, profile_name, poster_id, poster_name, message, countnum, postdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($ins);
$num = 1;
$stmt->bind_param('isissis', $pid, $pname, $user_id, $user, $comment, $num, $datetime);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: Plus, you're also using some wrong variables with one variable mispelled.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good point, maybe `$message` was intended to be in `$comment`'s place

Comment: @Ghost That is exactly what I thought also. I've posted my answer with the corrections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few variables that don't match.

`$poster_id` - `$poster_name` - `$message`

that are aligned with and in your binds:

`$user_id, $user, $comment`

---

This should work now:

```
<?php

$pid = '1'; 
$pname = 'name'; 
$poster_id = '2';
$poster_name = 'name2'; 
$message = 'This is the message';

$datetime = date("M d, Y");

// insert into database
$ins  = "INSERT INTO messages (profile_id, profile_name, poster_id, poster_name, message, countnum, postdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($ins);
$num = 1;
$stmt->bind_param('isissis', $pid, $pname, $poster_id, $poster_name, $message, $num, $datetime);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Yet, you should replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

in order to catch the errors.

Also add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

which would have signaled an undefined variable warning.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

***An insight***

As pointed out by Ghost:

`$datetime` format `M d, Y` is suspicious too, it could screw up `Y-m-d H:i:s`'s format of column `DATETIME` if its indeed that way.

therefore you may need to change

```
$datetime = date("M d, Y");
```

to

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

or

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d");
```

depending on what your column type is set to.

Comment: this `$datetime` format `M d, Y` is suspicious too, could screw up `Y-m-d H:i:s`'s format of column `DATETIME` if its indeed that way.

Comment: @Ghost *Hm...* you have a point there. I will add that in an edit at the bottom, kudos to you.

Comment: So is there somewhere I can give you guys a thumbs up or something like that for the info. I really appreciate everyone's help.